# substring Windows Forms

Tags: c#, indexing, substring

My idea is to input a word into **TextBoxWord**, and put another word into another textbox **textBoxLitera** and receive a number of **textBoxLitera.text** words in my **TextBoxWord.text**.
The program is giving me a good answer but throws an Exception

*index and length must refer to a location within the string. parameter name length*.

```
namespace Literki
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnLitery_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int LetterCount = 0;
            string letter = "";

            string text = TextBoxWord.Text;
            string wyr = textBoxLitera.Text;
            int w = wyr.Length;

            for (int i=0;i<text.Length;i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    letter = text.Substring(i, w);
                }
                catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException f)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(f.Message);
                }

                if (letter == textBoxLitera.Text)
                    LetterCount++;
            }
            MessageBox.Show(LetterCount.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?
(Sorry for my language, it's my first post here)
Thanks for help!

Comment: You really need to step through your code using a debugger to find the problem. It will be very obvious and you'll be able to fix this issue yourself in the future.

Comment: Some example input and expected output would have been helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `i` is at the end of the string and you try to substring `w` characters (where `w > 1`) it will fail.

For example, for the word "four", the maximum index is 3 (`"Four"[3]` returns "r"). Let's see what happens when we try a length > 0 at the end of the string.

```
"Four".Substring(3, 4) // throws an exception
"Four".Substring(3, 1) // returns "r"
```

You'll need to ensure that:

1. `w` isn't longer than the length of `text`. This will always throw an exception.
2. The code must not substring beyond the end of `text`. One way to do this would be to change the condition on the for-loop to `i <= text.Length - w`

Comment: In this case this will never return the last characters of my word.

Comment: Example input and expected output please! :) Did you miss that I changed the operator from `<` to `<=`?

Comment: Oh yea i missed it, sorry mate:)you were right in the begining

Answer (score 0):

In fact the condition should be

```
 for (int i=0;i<text.Length -w+1;i++)
```